# How can I reduce the space between selected option and the dropdown icon in react-native picker?

Tags: react-native

I am implementing picker in mobile app, but the space between the icon and the option is too much

Answer (score -1):

You just have to make that the picker don't get whole space. To make this add it flex = 0. like this:

```
<Picker ... style={{ flex: 0 }} ... />
```

Comment: add it alignItems: 'center' too